# How do I reuse the same instance of a component in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I built a single-page app in Nuxt.js 2 and Vue2. This has a very heavy WebGL visualizer that displays a 3D scene in two separate pages: `SectionDesign` and `SectionConfirm`

```vue
<template>
    <SectionDesign v-if="currentPage === 1"></SectionDesign>
    <SectionPurchase v-if="currentPage === 2"></SectionPurchase>
    <SectionConfirm v-if="currentPage === 3"></SectionConfirm>
</template>
```

My problem is that when I navigate from page 1 to page 2, my `<canvas>` gets destroyed, I lose WebGL context, and all the loaded assets disappear. I have to re-initialize everything when I enter page 3. This is very resource-intensive and unoptimized. I'd like to create my `<canvas>` only once, then "move it" from one section to the next.

I can do this with vanilla Javascript by [appending a child to a new parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```js
const canvas = document.getElementByID("myCanvas");
page1.appendChild(canvas);

function enterPage3() {
    page3.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

This re-uses the same instance of the canvas, it just moves it to a new parent. Is there a way to achieve this with Vue2 and Nuxt.js?

Comment: Vanilla JS will still need to wire that to the DOM, so it's quite as resource intensive too. 
You could put it into a wrapper, like a `layout` or a page on top of the others, should be enough. Otherwise, you can always try to see if [portal-vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue) is relevant in your case (this is basically this Teleport [documentation page](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html) from Vue3).

Comment: Otherwise, you can also use either a [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) or even just a simple `v-show`. Depends on what you do prefer here.

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt has build in components like `KeepAlive` that does not destroy your component / element

`caches the inactive component instances without destroying them`

Just wrap it

```
<KeepAlive>
   <component />
</KeepAlive>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I append this `<component>` as a child of the first `<section>` and then move that same instance to the third `<section>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using layouts, create one as **default.vue** into **/layouts** dir.

Then use your WebGL viewer in the layout:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- YourViewer component keeps visible in all pages using this layout -->
    <YourViewer />
    <!-- Every page is loaded inside nuxt tag -->
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the component to be a *child* of each section. What you're suggesting would simply place it higher up in the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: I do not know about your templates or sections but you can define a template into the layout that allows to place your viewer where you want. If this solution is not valid for your case, you can use the keep-alive attr in the <nuxt> component. Then you can define how many components must be destroyed every route change: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components#keep-alive

Comment: @Marquizzo as [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71947488/how-do-i-reuse-the-same-instance-of-a-component-in-nuxt-js/71965878?noredirect=1#comment127135226_71947488).